# How to hide the virtual keypad by clicking outside of an EditText?

Tags: android, android-virtual-keyboard

I am new to Android development. My requirement is that I want to hide the android virtual keypad when I click on the outside of an EditText widget. Please help.

Comment: Some great answers below. Keep in mind that it is normal for android users to click the back or done button to dismiss the keyboard as opposed to touching outside the edittext like one would do on an iPhone.

Comment: when i am pressing the back button , app is going to be closed

Comment: Generally when the keyboard is open and I would like to leave the app I expect to press back once to dismiss the keyboard and then back again to leave the current visible activity. If that is the last activity in the stack then I would expect to have "quit" the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide the virtual keyboard you can execute the following code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Simply put that code inside the `onTouchDown()` method of an `OnTouchListener` that is tied to the parent layout.

Comment: This wrapped in the overridden dispatchTouchEvent() as suggested by Ram in the other answer worked great.

Comment: ya it will get closed but if u click second edittext (if available) it wont get focus. the keypad doesn't get open. please give another answer. i tried lot form stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Just check this.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
View view = getCurrentFocus();
boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

if (view instanceof EditText) {
    View w = getCurrentFocus();
    int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
    w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
    float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
    float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
&& (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() 
|| y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) { 
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
return ret;
}
```

Override this method where you have edit text in your activity..

Comment: @miek If you remove coordinate checks, then the keyboard won't show the next time you click on EditText.